# How can a type have multiple supertypes which are array types, and not itself be an array type?

Tags: java, types, specifications, inference

I'm trying to code an implementation of type inference, using the algorithm outlined in the Java spec, at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.2.3

There is a line here with some implications I'm struggling to understand:

"...among the supertypes of S that are array types, a most specific type is identified, S'[] (this may be S itself)."

How can S itself *not* be the most specific array type? In other words, how can a type have supertypes which are array types, and not itself be an array type (and therefore of the most specific kind)?

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks for any insight anyone can offer...

Comment: Your title doesn't accurately represent your actual question.

Comment: The title question is equivalent to the description. I repeat the title question almost word for word *in* the description...

Comment: The  you've misunderstood the passage you cited. It doesn't say anything about *S* not being an array type. It just implies that *S* may not be the 'most specific' type.

Comment: But if S *is* an array type, then it directly follows that it is the most specific array type of it and all its supertypes. It can't have a supertype which is more specific than it, that literally cannot happen by definition...

Comment: Besides, the question has been resolved. S can be a wildcard type, or possibly an intersection type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a Double[] and the options are Number[] or Object[] then Number[] is the most specific match.  When performing type inference, there might be multiple constraints.  It might even infer the type (Serializable[] & Comparable[])

Comment: Yeah, now I've asked the question - and thanks also to a now deleted comment on the question - I've realised there are a number of ways we can have things like wildcard types with upper boundings on array types, and intersection types involving array types, etc... Ah well, I'll have a bit more of a think about it then probably just mark this as accepted.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I don't think that ? extends CharSequence[] is actually a type. I'm not entirely sure what it is though. I've tried and failed on many occasions to understand java generics and types, but they're totally incomprehensible.

Comment: Nah, you were totally right, at least within the context of the question. In experimenting with this I've just discovered a few bugs in Eclipse's type inference implementation too, haha, which both makes me feel better about my silly question, and intimidates me. Cheers.

Comment: In the unlikely event that anyone else needs an answer to this question, though it is not explicitly stated by the spec, I *think* the algorithm is such that S cannot be a wildcard type in this context, though it may be an intersection type. Wildcards should be dealt with by containment constraints, and not encountered by subtype constraints.